# exit and clean up python fork

Tags: python, linux, fork, htop

i am trying to code socket server with fork in python. somehow a new fork will be created when a client is connected and this fork process will handle the connection including send/receive.
i ran this script on Linux `centOS` and monitor resources with `htop/top` to see how many forks (task) are shown. the
problem is  when i kill some fork by using `os._exit(0)` htop won't be changed (naturally it has to be decreased by killing forks) and when i close python script every thing will be back to normal ( Ram usage and tasks ).
so what i have to do that when i kill some fork by using `os._exit(0)`, it effects on `htop` in other hand releases all resources and do not wait until its own parent is killed ?
here it's the code to create forks:

```
def test(sock):
     //handle socket then return
for i in range (1000):
     sock,addr=socket.accept()
     pid=os.fork()
     if pid==0:
          test(sock)
          os._exit(0)
     elif pid !=-1:
          os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent process needs to wait for the child in order for the child process' resources to be released. Until then the process still exists in a "zombie" state, and it will still appear in `ps` and `top` etc.

You can call one of [`os.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.wait), [`os.waitpid()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.waitpid),  [`os.wait3()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.wait3), or [`os.wait4()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.wait4).

`os.wait3()` with the `os.WNOHANG` option might be most useful to you as it will wait for any child process and the parent will not block until a child terminates (or it's state changes - `wait` will return child processes that have been stopped or restarted too).

More details on the underlying system calls can be found in the Linux man page: [`man 2 wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).

Comment: i used `os.waitpid(childPID,0)` in parent . but the parent does not accept any more connection until the child process done and exits.but i need when i use `os._exit(0)` in fork process it disapear in ps or top . in other hand release all resources . but now if i create 1000 forks and even destroy them all ( `os._exit(0)` ) it seems `top or ps` still shows tasks=1000. it seems fork have not been clean or something like that. but when i terminate python process and stop every it then every thing gonna be ok

Comment: @MehrdadDadvand: the parent will not accept any more connections because it is blocked waiting for the child to terminate. You can run `os.waitpid(childPID,os.WNOHANG)` and the parent will not block, and will return `(0, return_code)` indicating that the child terminated, or (childPID, return_code) if it didn't. I mentioned `os.wait3(os.WNOHANG)` in my answer, which is almost the same as `os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG), but it returns extra resource info about the child which might be useful to log in your parent process.

Comment: i think still there is small problem here . i used `os.waitpid(-1,os.WNOHANG)` and `tasks` in top is not going to update with fork termination . but it is not going to increase like Previous code.

Comment: i can see a lot of task zombie field in `top` when i run my scripy. i think task are still in zombie state

Comment: It's difficult to comment without seeing the code in question. Are you calling `os.waitpid()` many times? What is it returning? - is it actually returning the PID of a terminated child, or 0 (in which case it didn't join with any child).? Perhaps you could add to your questinon a minimal working example of your code.